# run script from Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a script from Java.  I tried doing this in my main class.

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./test_exec.sh", "hello world");
    Process p = pb.start();
```

I'm building the project through maven and test_exec.sh is included as a resource.  When I unarchive the jar, I see the test_exec.sh file at the root directory.  Why can't Java see the file?  I've also tried `test_exec.sh` without the `./` in front of it.

The error I get is:

```
 Cannot run program "./test_exec.sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
```

I've also tried:

```
Path currentPath = Paths.get("", "test_exec.sh").toAbsolutePath();
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(currentPath.toString(), "hello world");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: I think, you should paste stack trace of error if you get any.

Comment: Is your path correct ? Is the script file in class folder or jar folder ? Try to give absolute path manualy

Comment: I'm new to Java so what I do know is it's included as a resource in src/main/resources using Maven. The output jar that I unarchived does have the test_exec.sh script file in the root folder of that jar.

Comment: You actually lack the executable (the shell executable), you should put the path to the shell first.

Comment: @JeremyGrand is correct. Or give the scripts absolute path correct...

Comment: @JeremyGrand Is there a platform specific way to do that so it can be deployed to different run times?

Comment: @Cristal I actually do that in my application (and compliant with both Windows and Unix OS), but it's not code I would show to someone who is "new to java". You should get the path to the shell executable file with which you run those sh files. You probably can declare it as an environment variable and inject it as a property in your class.

Comment: @JeremyGrand So if the command, like `bash` is an environment variable, I wouldn't have to give the absolute path then?

Comment: @Crystal Are you running your application directly from the jar file (java -jar)?

Comment: @whbogado The end goal would be yes. Right now I'm just running it from Intellij.

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @Crystal The IDE runs the jar file. The operating system will not look inside a jar file for the script. To run a script like that you must extract it to be accessible from the file system. No matter how you set the path it won't work.

Comment: @Cristal The `ProcessBuilder` won't parse your environment variables to get the proper path on its own, but you can, however, get the path from the `BASH_HOME` environment variable using `System.getenv("BASH_HOME")`.

Comment: @JeremyGrand can you answer the question with gettig BASH_HOME as an environment variable. I got it to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Crystal I tried to, but the question has been (wrongly, in my opinion) closed as a duplicate before I could answer. That's why I only answered in comments.